# Is it possible to combine \column and \table?

Tags: tables, beamer

I hope this post finds you in good health. I need to replicate what's in the picture. I have been trying to add my table to the `\begin{columns}` but I am afraid that I have been unsuccessful. I am sure I am missing something but unable to understand what.

May I please request your assistance in the matter.

Part of my code:

```
    \begin{frame}{The Lights Out Game}
    The game consists of a 5 by 5 grid of lights; at the start some of them are switched on. Pressing one of the lights will toggle it and the four adjacent lights on and off. The challenge is to get to the point where all lights are off. Here is an example.
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}
            \begin{table}[tb]
                \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
                    \hline
                    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                    &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                    &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                    &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                    &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
            \end{table}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

The error I get is `Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{frame}`

[image: Nested Column and Table]

Comment: just remove the `table` environment it is not doing anything useful, you can use `tabular` directly in the column.

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle tried it. It doesn't work: `  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}
     \begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|l|l|l|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
      &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
      &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
      &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
      &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
   \end{column}
  \end{columns}`

Comment: The width argument is also missing. You might want to go for something like `\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}`.

Comment: It will work, you must have made an error somewhere. If you have code that gives an error you should put a complete small test document in the question, and show the error that you get. (@leandriis just spotted the error)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was due to syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

As per @leandriis the below works! Thank you very much for your help and assistance

```
 \vspace{2ex}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.2\textwidth}
                \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
                    \hline
                    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                    &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                    &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                    &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                    &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
            \hfill\
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.8\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \vspace{-3ex}
                \item At the start the 13 lights shown are on.
                \item We press one light (shown in red)
                \item This is the result; continue in this way.
                \item Success!
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
```